# Is target API level 16 application able to run in the API level 18 devices?

Tags: android

Here is an example that describes the problem. I created an application which have the  `android:targetSdkVersion="16"` set. 
Example:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Is target API level 16 application able to run in the API level 18 devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Always include these two tags:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

**2.** **NEVER** include this tag:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:maxSdkVersion="19" />
```

**3.** Preferably you should always compile with the latest API level:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

What you put in the `targetSdkVersion` tag is what your application is compiled with.

Android applications are generally **forward compatible**, so your application will run on **ALL** devices with API level >= `android:minSdkVersion` and API level <= `android:maxSdkVersion`. For this reason you should never use the `android:maxSdkVersion` tag.

So the answer to your question is **YES** !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will work. Android is downwards-compatible. Only the other way round may cause problems depending on what APIs you use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, android device api level 18 supports application which contains target version api level 16. However, it is a good practice to set this value to match the API level of the platform on which it's running. This will enable the latest features supported by that platform within your application itself.

**android:targetSdkVersion**

> An integer designating the API Level that the application targets. If
>   not set, the default value equals that given to minSdkVersion. This
>   attribute informs the system that you have tested against the target
>   version and the system should not enable any compatibility behaviors
>   to maintain your app's forward-compatibility with the target version.
>   The application is still able to run on older versions (down to
>   minSdkVersion).
>
> As Android evolves with each new version, some behaviors and even
>   appearances might change. However, if the API level of the platform is
>   higher than the version declared by your app's targetSdkVersion, the
>   system may enable compatibility behaviors to ensure that your app
>   continues to work the way you expect. You can disable such
>   compatibility behaviors by specifying targetSdkVersion to match the
>   API level of the platform on which it's running. For example, setting
>   this value to "11" or higher allows the system to apply a new default
>   theme (Holo) to your app when running on Android 3.0 or higher and
>   also disables screen compatibility mode when running on larger screens
>   (because support for API level 11 implicitly supports larger screens).

SOURCE -[android:targetSdkVersion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target)

Answer (score 0):

your ans is yes it will support.

**1.)** `android:minSdkVersion=` Mins the application is not support below versions you declared here.

**e.g.**`android:minSdkVersion=16` then your application is not support below the 16 API. you must your application at 16 or above versions.

**2.)**`android:targetSdkVersion=` Your application is build at this API level.

**e.g.**`android:targetSdkVersion=18` then your application is build with the latest(mins selected) API level classes.

**3.)**`android:maxSdkVersion=` Your Application is not supported the above version you declared.

**e.g.** `android:maxSdkVersion=19` then your application is not supported above then 19 you must install your application up to you declared levels API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It able to run above API level 14 upto latest one.